# Merge branch 'X' of URL into X

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-commit

When I and my colleague work on the same git branch, each of us sees a strange commit with message

"Merge branch 'X' of URL into X"

where X - the same branch.

after pull has been performed (and new changes came from remote).
I said "strange" because I previously work with SVN, and this process in SVN is transparent - SVN doesn't create a commit when I perform "svn update" in order to obtain changes from server.

Is it possible to avoid such commits? They litters log history...

Answer (score 6):

Instead of merging upstream changes into your own respective branches, rebase your branches against the upstream prior to a push. Use the `--rebase` option to `git pull` or set the `branch.<name>.rebase` option in ~/.gitconfig to enable that option by default. If you consistently do this you'll get a nice linear history.

Rebasing branches is something that should be done with caution and with an understanding of how the process works. Specifically, don't rebase commits that have been published, i.e. left your own personal workspace via a push. Up until that happens, feel free to rework your commits by rebasing, squashing or whatever you need to do before they're fit for being published to the world.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. How do you merge X into X if X is already X?

Comment: A branch name like X can mean different things in different contexts. The master branch at http://... is typically called origin/master in your local workspace, but from the perspective of the remote git it's the master branch.

Comment: @MagnusBäck I have tried to rebase X branch on top of develop from source, after resolving the conflict and clicking continue rebase. X branch started showing A-Ahead and B-Behind again to resolve this I have pulled and pushed. Automatically source tree adding new commit message "Merge branch X of URL into X", which I dont want. How can I achieve this? How can I avoid autocommit  message "Merge branch X of URL into X" from source on top of my current branch after rebase.